# Increasing the Elements of an Array Like a Number

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm attempting to make a Sudoku solving program. To reach the puzzle's solution, the program interprets 0's as empty slots, and then makes an array that has a length equivalent to the number of zeros in the entire puzzle. From there, it sets all of the values in the array to 1 (the minimum value any slot can have in a Sudoku puzzle). What I'm trying to do is simulate a number's incremental pattern in the array starting from the element with the greatest index.

For example, a puzzle with three empty slots would result in an array of 3 elements. The array would then increase based on the pattern mention above:

0 0 0 (Initiation) 
1 1 1 (Set to possible values) 
1 1 2 
1 1 3 
1 1 4
1 1 5
1 1 6
1 1 7
1 1 8
1 1 9
1 2 1 (Skips 1 2 0 since it would include a 0)
1 2 2
etc.

This is a modified form of a base 10 number increment. Instead of 0-9, it uses 1-9. How may I build a method that will increment the array in this manner?

Comment: People here only write code for you if you already have written some code and run into a problem.

Comment: Just create a string `("" + array[0] + array[1] + array[2])` then parse that as an integer add 1 then convert to string and use `charAt(0) chartAt(1) charAt(2)`...

Comment: @9000 There's not really anything that I could write to run into the mentioned problem. I could include the initiation, the setting of the values, and then a broken `for` loop that doesn't solve the problem, but that doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: That would be helpful. Please include that in your post.

Comment: I don't think an array of every possible combintation is feasible to do in a computer.  There are billions of possible combinations from an initial starting soduku position.  Perhaps looking into AI algorithms such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm is better

Comment: At least you could search by keyword and find [`functools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) :)

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm here is to increment the right most digit then, if it overflows, increment the next to the left and so on. Recursion is a neat way of solving this. I'll do it in pseudocode and leave you to convert to Java

```
function increment(array, digit)
    if (array[digit] < 9)
        array[digit] += 1
    else if (digit > 0)
        array[digit] == 1;
        increment(array, digit - 1)
    else
        you are finished
```

Then each time you call this with: `increment(array, array.length - 1)`