# Checking if a word is already in a list (Bash)

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm writing a small bash script and am trying to test is a newly generated word is already in a list of all previously made words.

This is what I'm working with now:

```
dict=("word1"... "word21") #there would be 21 words in here
prev_guesses=()

guess_creator() {
    guess=""
    for i in {1..5} ;
    do 
        guess_num=$( shuf -i 0-21 -n 1 )
        guess+="${dict[$guess_num]}"
    done

    # using recursion to take another guess

    if [ $guess (is in)  $prev_guesses] ; then
        guess_creator
    else 
        prev_guess+=($guess)
    fi

}
```

I'm also not sure if recursion works like this in bash. If it doesn't, I'm asking here how to actually "unbreak" this code.The idea is to have this function constantly outputting a unique string every time it runs so I can use it later on in the script.

I have three questions:

1. How can I compare `guess` to the list `prev_guesses` and get a `true` or `false` output
2. How can I append guessed string to the list `prev_guesses` (I just checked it and it is just concatenating the strings together, I need a list like `prev_guesses=("guess1" "guess2"...)` - I may have solved this with the final edit.
3. Does this recursion in `guess_creator` work?

Comment: What is your question here? to do recursion or to see if a given word is an array?

Comment: But then `guess` , do you plan to use it in a variable or array context?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Finally the value of `prev_guesses` is permutations(if order matters) or combinations of five words from dict list, is that your want? There will be `21*20*19*18*17` or `21*20*19*18*17/5*4*3*2*1` possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Associative Arrays

Since you are only interested in »is this word in the list or not?« but not in the order of entries, you could use an *associative array* (also known as dictionary or hash map) to store your words. Checking whether an entry is in such a map is very fast (time complexity *O*(1)):

```
declare -A oldGuesses=([word1]= [word2]= [word3]=)
if [[ "${oldGuesses[$guess]+1}" ]]; then
    echo "$guess was already taken"
else 
    echo "$guess was not taken yet"
fi
```

You can add an entry to `dict` using

```
dict["newEntry"]=
```

Don't worry about the empty right hand side. Maps are normally used to store key-value pairs. Here we only use the keys (the things which are written inside the `[]`).

#### Avoiding the list of guesses completely

You mentioned that you want to bruteforce and that the list could grow up to 4M entries. I would advise against using bash, but even more against storing all guesses at all (no matter what language you are using).

Instead, enumerate all possible guesses in an ordered way:

You want to create guesses which are five concatenated words? 
Just create five for-loops:

```
for w1 in "${dict[@]}"; do
  for w2 in "${dict[@]}"; do
    for w3 in "${dict[@]}"; do
      for w4 in "${dict[@]}"; do
        for w5 in "${dict[@]}"; do
          guess="$w1$w2$w3$w4$w5"
          # do something with your guess here
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

Benefits of this approach over your old approach:

- Don't have to store 4M guesses.
- Don't have to search through 4M guesses whenever taking a new guess.
- Guarantees that the same guess is not picked over and over again.
- Terminates when all possible guesses are made.

Comment: That could work, but how would I append a new item to the array? If you look at my code you'll see that if a word is not already in the list, I need to add it so the next iterations of `guess_creator` can keep finding unique words.

Comment: Is there a neater way to code that? It's a great idea that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: There is a [better way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27952881/6770384) (especiialy if you plan to concatenate more than five words) but in this case it's not really shorter. In bash you also could use [brace expansion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97814/187122) but that would be a bit risky because bash will expand all 4M combinations before iterating over them.

Comment: Yeah, I just switched over to python and made a working script in about 4 minutes. I guess I learned something from playing with bash though.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's nothing like that in bash for arrays (Socowi's idea of using Associative Array is better), you would have to iterate through the list again, or maybe try to use grep or something
2. to refer to all the elements of an array you need the syntax `${prev_guesses[*]}`

so you can concatenate with something like

```
prev_guesses=(${prev_guesses[*]} $guess)
```

Spaces in your words would make it all more complicated

3. It should do. BUT....

That's the hard way. If you want to avoid repeating guesses, better to take out each guess from the array when you take it, so you can't take it again.

Easier still is to use the shuf commmand to do everything

```
    guess=($( shuf -e ${dict[*]} -n 5))
```

shuffle your words and take the first five

Comment: Well unfortunately this list would end up being *really* big. Maybe bash is just not suited for this then. I was planning on using this to brute force an old .gpg file I had and the list would end up being about 4 million items long. Can bash even handle something like that?

Comment: It might handle it, technically, but I think you would be much better off with python or pretty much anything else, really.

Comment: Never use bash to bruteforce something! As an exercise, I once had the task to reverse a hash of a five character password with only lowercase lettters and numbers. I aborted the bash script after four days and wrote a java (which can also be slow) program instead, which solved the task in two minutes.